# Pandas dataframe assign 0 with all the value after first non-nan value

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with several columns and a series whose value are the index of the first non-nan value of the dataframe:

dataframe x:

```
    a    b    c    d    e     f    g    h 
1   nan  nan  2    nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
2   nan  2    nan  10   23   nan  nan  nan
3   3    nan  23   42   232  3    nan  5
```

series y:

```
a   3
b   2
c   1
d   2
e   2
f   3
g   nan
h   3
```

now I want to assign 0 with all the value after first non-nan value(include the first non-nan value) by the value of series(whose value are the index of the first non-nan value of the dataframe x)

result is

```
    a    b    c    d    e     f    g    h 
1   nan  nan  0    nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
2   nan  0    0    0    0    nan  nan  nan
3   0    0    0    0    0    0    nan  0
```

I use applymap to deal with it,but applymap seems not to deal with index information,here is my code:

```
def mycode(x,y)
if x.index<=Y:
        return 0
    else:
        return x

cal = x.applymap(lambda x: mycode(x,y))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ffill` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `method='ffill'`) with [`clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
x = x.ffill().clip(0,0)
```

Alternative solutions with boolean mask and [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) or 
[`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
x = x.where(x.ffill().isnull(), 0)
```

```
x = x.mask(x.ffill().notnull(), 0)
```

---

```
print (x)
     a    b    c    d    e    f   g    h
1  NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
2  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN NaN  NaN
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 NaN  0.0
```

Detail:

```
print (x.ffill())
     a    b     c     d      e    f   g    h
1  NaN  NaN   2.0   NaN    NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
2  NaN  2.0   2.0  10.0   23.0  NaN NaN  NaN
3  3.0  2.0  23.0  42.0  232.0  3.0 NaN  5.0

print (x.ffill().isnull())
       a      b      c      d      e      f     g      h
1   True   True  False   True   True   True  True   True
2   True  False  False  False  False   True  True   True
3  False  False  False  False  False  False  True  False
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This is what I want!